# Python WTForms RegEx Phone Number Validation Not Working

Tags: python, regex, validation, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm creating a form using WTForms that should take a phone number input in the format "xxx-xxx-xxxx" and for some reason, it is not doing its job.

```
phone = StringField(
    'phone',
    validators=[
        Regexp(
            regex=r"^\d{3}[-]{1}\d{3}[-]{1}\d{4}$",
            message="Valid phone number format is xxx-xxx-xxxx"
        )
    ]
)
```

I tried being more descriptive with my RegEx and I even tried writing a custom validator and it also didn't work.

```
import re
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError

def validatePhoneNum(form, field):
    if not re.search(r"\d{3}[-]\d{3}[-]\d{4}$", field.data):
        raise ValidationError("Invalid phone number")

phone = StringField(
    'phone',
    validators=[validatePhoneNum]
)
```

Comment: what are the values you tried?

Comment: 1231231234
123-123-1234
both of these passed the validation.

Comment: Sorry, no: [check online](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5E%5Cd%7B3%7D%5B-%5D%7B1%7D%5Cd%7B3%7D%5B-%5D%7B1%7D%5Cd%7B4%7D%24&test_string=1231231234%0A123-123-1234&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0). So, what is the actual problem you have?

Comment: Exactly, the first one shouldn't pass, yet it does. No errors are thrown and the invalid values are stored in the database.

Comment: Well, as you can check on the linked page - the first **is not** matched by the regex. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: Yes, the 1231231234 input is not matched by regex in the page you linked as it should. However, in my flask application, when I use 1231231234 as input, the application behaves as if this regex validator doesn't exist at all. So obviously, this is not a regex problem. I'll provide updates if I find out where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. Your first solution was enough. YOu only needed to import Regexp from the form

```
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, AnyOf, URL, Regexp
```